# jQuery construct dynamic html tags

Tags: jquery, html

Can I not simply create a variable containing HTML constructed with variables?

```
<script>
var spanName = "Span1";
var yesButton = "YesRadioButton1";

var x = "<span id='" + spanName + "' class='yesno' style='visibility: hidden;'><asp:RadioButton ID='" + yesButton +"' runat='server'/></span>";
</script>
```

I've also tried using templates with no luck.

```
var x = [
    "<span id='" + spanName + "' class='yesno' style='visibility: hidden\'>",
        "<asp:RadioButton ID='" + yesButton  +"' runat='server'>",
    "</span>"
].join("\n");
```

Both attempts don't like the + yesButton + code.

I'm trying to attach dynamic html after a tag.

Comment: You can create HTML in JS and append it to the DOM. However *you cannot create server-side controls in JS*, as it's far too late in the page lifecycle. You need to create your ASP.Net controls on the server side. Either use AJAX to retrieve them, or a Postback.

Comment: `don't like the + yesButton + code` - what does that mean? Are you seeing errors?  If yes, edit your question and include them.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. I knew that but forgot. :(